# Handling Typographies seamlessly for all range of devices

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

This is my theme configuration in Mui+react project

const theme = createTheme({
palette: pallete,
typography: {
htmlFontSize: 18,
"@media (min-width:1520px)": {
htmlFontSize: 40
},
fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
h1: {
fontWeight: 500,
fontSize: "2.5rem",
lineHeight: "1.125rem",
letterSpacing: "-0.01562em",
"@media (max-width: 730px)": {
fontSize: "1.8rem",
lineHeight: "2rem"
}
},

```
h5: {
  fontSize: "1.875rem",
  lineHeight: "1.25rem",

  "@media(min-width:1520px)": {
    fontSize: "2.175rem",
    lineHeight: "1.45rem"
  },
  "@media (min-width: 1920px)": {
    fontSize: "2.5rem",
    lineHeight: "1.66rem"
  }
},
h6: {
  fontSize: "1.5rem",
  fontWeight: "500",
  lineHeight: "normal"
},
subtitle1: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "0.75rem",
  fontWeight: 500,
  lineHeight: "1.25rem",

  "@media (max-width: 1200px)": {
    fontSize: "0.7rem"
  }
},
subtitle2: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "0.625rem",
  lineHeight: "1.25rem",
  "@media (max-width: 600px)": {
    fontSize: "0.6rem"  
  }
},
body1: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "1rem",
  fontWeight: 340,
  lineHeight: "1.26rem",
  "@media (max-width: 600px)": {
    fontSize: "0.75rem", 
    lineHeight: "0.9rem"
  },
  "@media (max-width: 900px)": {
    fontSize: "0.85rem", 
    lineHeight: "1rem"
  }
},

summaryCardTitle: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "0.875rem",
  fontWeight: "600",
  lineHeight: "1.25rem",
  "@media (max-width: 600px)": {
    fontSize: "0.71rem", 
    lineHeight: "1rem"
  }

},
reportCardTitle: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "1rem",
  fontWeight: "600",
  lineHeight: "1.25rem",
  "@media (max-width: 600px)": {
    fontSize: "0.9rem",
    lineHeight: "1.1rem"
  }
},
buttonText: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "0.875rem",
  fontWeight: "600"
},
caption: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "0.85rem",
  lineHeight: "1.125rem",
  "@media (max-width: 450px)": {
    fontSize: "0.60rem", 
    lineHeight: "0.91rem"
  }

},
formLabel: {
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  fontSize: "0.75rem"
},
LayoutHeading: {
  fontSize: "1.25rem",
  fontWeight: "500",
  fontFamily: '"Inter", "Helvetica", "Arial", sans-serif',
  lineHeight: "1.25rem",
  "media(min-width:1920px)": {
    fontSize: "1.3125rem"
  }
}
```

}
})

In my MUI+React project, I've configured a theme with typography settings for various elements like headings, buttons, and captions. While I've been able to adjust font sizes for individual typography variants based on screen width using media queries, I'm curious why I can't directly apply media queries to dynamically adjust the root font size (htmlFontSize). This would allow for seamless scaling of font sizes across different screens, ensuring consistent typography regardless of device. Essentially, I'm seeking advice on achieving responsive typography and maintaining consistent font sizes across a range of devices, given a standard design for a particular screen size.

I tried adding media queries to change font size it did not worked,now currently iam adding media queries for different varients

Comment: Consider setting up a codepen or something with this code in it